# Converting apache rewrite rules to nginx for serving static files

Tags: python, apache, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a vhost with nginx:

- if it's a static file, send it to apache
- if it's a python file, send it to Python webserver

  ```
  server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name mywebsite.fr;

    index index.html index.htm;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/proxy-access-mywebsite.log proxylog;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/proxy-error-mywebsite.log error;


    # vhost for static files
    location ~ ^/(static|public)/.* {
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Server $host;
      proxy_pass http://apache$uri;
    }

    location / {
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Server $host;
      proxy_pass http://mywebsite/;
    }
  }
  ```

In my Apache, I have those rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Remove all /
RewriteRule ^/static/CACHE/(.*) static/CACHE/$1
RewriteRule ^/static/(.*) static/production/$1
RewriteRule ^/public/(.*) uploads/$1

# If file, stop
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule . - [QSA,L]

# Let's try with full path, if file then rewrite + stop:
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f
RewriteRule (.*) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/production/$1 -f
RewriteRule (.*) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/production/$1 [QSA,L]
```

But I'm just realizing that it's stupid to pass to Apache: nginx could act itself as a cache for static files!

I'd like to rewrite those rules for the nginx server, but so far nothing works. I think my big problem is to test if it's a file with the full path and if so, then act as a cache server and send it immediately back.

How would you those 8 lines of apache rewrite rules to Nginx ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my working configuration

```
upstream mywebsite {
    ip_hash;
    server 127.0.0.1:8006;
}

server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;

    index index.html index.htm;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/proxy-access-mywebsite.log proxylog;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/proxy-error-mywebsite.log error;

    # ~ = regular expression
    # ~* = regular expression case *insensitive*
    location ~* ^/static/(?<p>.+) {
        root /web/htdocs/mywebsite/htdocs/static;
        try_files /$p /production/$p =403;
        access_log off;
        expires 1h;
    }
    location ~* ^/public/(?<p>.+) {
        root /web/htdocs/mywebsite/htdocs/uploads;
        try_files /$p =403;
        access_log off;
        expires 1h;
    }
    location / {
        expires -1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Server $host;
        proxy_pass http://mywebsite/;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with rules like the ones bellow?

```
# nginx configuration
location /static {
rewrite ^/static/CACHE/(.*) /static/CACHE/$1;
rewrite ^/static/(.*) /static/production/$1;
}
location /public {
rewrite ^/public/(.*) /uploads/$1;
}
location / {
rewrite ^(.*)$ /$document_root/$1 break;
rewrite ^(.*)$ /$document_root/production/$1 break;
}
```

You have to try different combinations since nginx rules can be tricky and without actually testing the rules it's really hard to convert them and actually work with the 1st attempt.

**SET THE LOG PATH/FILE**

```
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;

INSIDE OF HTTP SCOPE ADD ->

http {
rewrite_log on;
```

Comment: Is there a way to do a rewrite log trace like apache does?